# Library function: making a set as a list

Tags: java, list, set

Quick question about syntax in Java. I want to take a Set and return a List in a static method for a library. The following gives a compiler error and I don't know why:

```
public static List<T> asList(Set<T> keySet)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

The message is "T cannot be resolved to a type". But isn't that the syntax for a generic type in Java?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a generic method you need to put the type `<T>` before the return argument also e.g.

```
public static <T> List<T> asList(Set<T> keySet)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must specify that T is not a concrete type, but a generic type:

```
public static <T> List<T> asList(Set<T> keySet)
```

Note that there is a constructor in every List implementation that takes a collection as argument and does what this static method does. I'm not sure it's particularly useful:

```
List<Foo> list = new ArrayList<Foo>(setOfFoos);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `<T>`.You have to specify T.

```
private static <T> List<T> asList(Set<T> keySet) {
    return result;
}
```